# Folder1 and Folder2 logs not showing correctly in Batch files

Tags: loops, batch-file, recursion, directory

This should be simple but is not working correctly.

```
FOR /D %%d IN ("D:\Folder*") DO (
    FOR /R "%%d\logs" %%i IN (*) do echo %%i
)
pause
```

I have also tried:

```
FOR /D %%d IN ("D:\Folder*") DO (
    SET fld=%%d
    FOR /R "%fld%\logs" %%i IN (*) do echo %%i
)
pause
```

I feel that am missing something pretty basic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First code

```
FOR /D %%d IN ("D:\Folder*") DO (
    FOR /R "%%d\logs" %%i IN (*) do echo %%i
)
```

fails because you can not use a `for` replaceable parameter in the folder of a `for /r`. In the way the `for` parser works, the value to use as the starting folder used in the `/R` must be available before the `for /d` starts to execute.

Second code

```
FOR /D %%d IN ("D:\Folder*") DO (
    SET fld=%%d
    FOR /R "%fld%\logs" %%i IN (*) do echo %%i
)
```

fails because `%fld%` will not be parsed as you think. The full `for /d %%d` is parsed as only one command and all the `%var%` references inside this command are removed, being replaced with the value stored in the variables before starting to execute. You can not change a variable's value and retrieve the changed value inside the same command because while executing there is not any variable expansion included in the command, only the values the variables had when the command was parsed.

This is usually handled enabling delayed expansion so you can change where needed `%var%` into `!var!` to indicate to the parser that the variable expansion (value retrieval) should be delayed until the command is executed. So you could write something like

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /D %%d IN ("D:\Folder*") DO (
    SET "fld=%%d"
    FOR /R "!fld!\logs" %%i IN (*) do echo %%i
)
```

BUT this will also not work, for the same reason indicated in the first code. The value to use in `/R` is required at parse time.

So, how to solve the problem?

You can avoid having to indicate the folder in the `/R` by first changing  the current active directory to the folder being iterated by `for /D %%i`

```
for /d %%d in ("d:\Folder*") do (
    pushd "%%~fd\logs" && (
        for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i
        popd
    )
)
```

or you can place the inner loop in a separate subroutine

```
for /d %%d in ("d:\Folder*") do call :process "%%d"
goto :eof


:process folderPath
for /r "%~1\logs" %%i in (*) do echo %%i
goto :eof
```

or you can replace the inner recursive `for` with a `for /f` processing a recursive `dir`

```
for /d %%d in ("d:\Folder*") do (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%%~fd\logs" /a-d /b /s`) do echo %%i
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just simplify it.

```bat
For /D %%A In ("D:\Folder*") Do Where/R "%%~A" *
```