# for /r not working with another for variable

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

My script iterates through a list of user profile paths and copies a bunch of files into them. This works so far now I need to edit the copied .xml files so I thought I'll just add another for /r for these folders  and do my thing. But I can't get this script working and I really don't know why. It's only entering the for /r loop when I substitute !PATH! with a constant value.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f %%a in (users.txt) do (
    SET PATH1=%%a\appdata\local\lazarus
    for /R "!PATH1!" %%x in (*.xml) do (
        call :fart "DKIUSER" "%%a" "%%x"
    )
)
```

thats the content of my users.txt: 
C:\Users\DKIUSER
C:\Users\dkiuser.DCJAN 
C:\Users\ladmin

Comment: Maybe, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44514302/2861476) could help you.

Comment: `for /R` does not accept delayed expanded variables or other loop variable references to specify the root path; use [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) to intermittently switch to the new root path and do not specify root at `for /R` (so it defaults to the current directory)...

Comment: Related: [Get size of the sub folders only using batch command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38396348)

Comment: Also learn to keep it simple. There was no need for you to assign the path to an environmental variable. When you fix your code, use the FOR variable directly with the PUSHD command.